# How do I simulate an "Edit" or "Destroy" button click in Rails 3.2 w/ MiniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, minitest

How can I write an integration test for editing an item? My "create" test looks like this:

```
  it "lets a user create a product" do
    login_user
    click_link("Products")
    click_link("New")
    fill_in "Identifier", :with => "MyString"
    click_button "Create"
    assert page.has_content?("Product was successfully created")
  end
```

And that works great. What I am confused about is how to do the Edit and Destroy tests. My index page provides a list of all products. So first I use a factory to create a couple of products. Now I am in the situation where there are multiple "Edit" and "Destroy" buttons. I can't just say:

```
click_button "Destroy"
```

because there are two of them. How do I tell it which one to click?

And if I do get the correct "Destroy" button clicked, how do I hit the "OK" button in the Javascript window that pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Webrat, you can use the "within" selector.

The Webrat "within" method takes a CSS selector as an argument. Supposing your "Destroy" button is in a div with an id like "#product-2", you can isolate that button with:

```
within "#product-2" do |scope|
  scope.click_button "Destroy"
end
```

If you need to / would rather use XPath, you can do something like:

```
 response.should have_xpath(xpath) do |button|
   click_button(button)
 end
```

Alternatively, if you are using Capybara, then you can use the "find" method:

```
find("#product-2").find("button").click
find(:xpath, "//div/div/button").click
```